# Number of days between dates in Swift

Tags: swift

I found a very strange behavior in Swift's Calendar dateComponents(_:from:to:) function.

```
let a = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: 7), to: Date())!
let n1 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date(), to: a).day!
let n2 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date(), to: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: 7), to: Date())!).day!
print(a)
print(Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: 7), to: Date())!)
print(n1)
print(n2)
```

This prints:

```
2018-04-21 19:58:16 +0000
2018-04-21 19:58:16 +0000
6
7
```

What am I missing?

Comment: *Hint:* `Date()` returns different values in each call, the time advances.

Comment: When you try to refactor your code to reuse duplicated code it will behave different as @MartinR mentioned.

Comment: I understand what @MartinR writes, but it only took miliseconds at most for this code to execute, as the first two prints show. How to explain a difference of 1 whole day is what I don’t know

Comment: 7 days minus 1 millisecond is **6 days,** 23 hours, 59 minutes and 59.999 seconds.

Comment: I totally misunderstood what dateComponents does. I thought it returned calendar days, as in: from today at 11 PM to tomorrow at 1 AM there's one day of difference. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin said in his comment, the problem is that you're getting a new value of Date() at each step, and the last value is a fraction of a second late than the first.

Note that this code gives the expected output:

```
let now = Date()
let a = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: 7), to: now)!
let n1 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: now, to: a).day!
let n2 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: now, to: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: 7), to: now)!).day!
print(a)
print(Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: 7), to: now)!)
print(n1)
print(n2)
```

It works because all the dates are EXACTLY the same value, not values that differ by a fraction of a second.